# How to multiply two int variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am making a program to enter the radius and output the area and the perimeter:

```
 # Calculates the area and the perimeter of a circle given the radius
    puts "Enter a radius"
    radius = gets
    area = radius * 3.14 * radius
    perimeter = 2 * 3.14 * radius

    puts area
    puts perimeter
```

When I tried to execute the code, it returned:

```
area.rb:4:in `*': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

The compiler says that the error is on the fourth line, but far I don't see any problems.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `radius` is a string, because `gets` always returns a string. Maybe it contains an integer, but it's a string representation of an integer, like `'10.3'`.

```
radius = gets.to_i
```

or if you need decimal values

```
radius = gets.to_f
```

It's a bit more complex than this because `to_i` and `to_f` give you  `0` and `0.0` respectively if you called them on `'foo'`. In that case you could use the `Integer` and `Float` methods, and they will give you an `ArgumentError` exception if they are not able to convert to an integer or float value.